# How do I set a variable during runtime on a Start() or awake method that I can use in Update()?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I set a variable during runtime on a Start() or awake method that I can use in Update()?

Here is what I have tried.

```
public class Unlock : MonoBehaviour
{
    // I want to set this to a random number on start or awake
    public string password;

   
    void Start()
    {
        // So I set a string of a random number to compare later to a text box.
        string password = (Random.Range(10, 350) / 10 * 10 ).ToString();
        print(password);
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // I can never get this to print the randomly set number. Please help :)
        print(password)  
    }
}
```

Comment: Classic case of shadowing an existing field. Your local `string password` hides the class field inside of `Start` -> inside of `Start` the name `password` always refers to the local variable, in `Update` you access the class field with the same name which is never assigned.

Answer (score 1):

You declared a local variable called `password` in `Start()`, shadowing the global version of `password`. Simply remove the declaration inside `Start()` will fix your issue:

```
    void Start()
    {
        // So I set a string of a random number to compare later to a text box.
        password = (Random.Range(10, 350) / 10 * 10 ).ToString();   // like so
        print(password);
    }
```

Comment: OKAY I FIXED IT! I just needed to run the line of code in a method that returned a string. Run the method in start()/awake(), Then I can access the returned value in Update()... derp :/

Comment: @WarSaw nope .. your mistake was rather shadowing your existing field by creating a local variable with the same name ... you only had to remove the `string` from `string password = ...` in `Start`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GameplayTaskManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public string password;

    // I made a new method that returned the value I wanted.
    string Password()
    {
        // This gets a string of a random number
        password = ((Random.Range(10, 350) / 10) * 10).ToString();
        return password;
    }
   
    void Start()
    {
        //Sets the string of the number one time
        Password();
    }

 void Update()
    {
        //This returns the value in start() not zero like before :)
        print(password);
    }
```